# Number of processors / Number of cores per processor Intel Core 2 Duo

Tags: vmware

I'm confused about years, what is the correct setting for this processor **Intel Core 2 Duo**, here is the [specification](http://ark.intel.com/products/33909/Intel-Core2-Duo-Processor-E8200-6M-Cache-2_66-GHz-1333-MHz-FSB).

I can set Number of processors to 2 and Number of cores to 1 or
I can set Number of processors to 1 and Number of cores to 2 and both setting works.

From my point of view the second option is right, because I have physically only one processor on the motherboard.

Thank you for confirmation and comments.

Comment: Looking at that specification you linked you have 1 processor with 2 cores, and no hyper threading capability, so it looks like what you stated is correct.  I would specify as listed 1 processor with 2 cores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must consider always the processor as the physical unit. So, Core2Duo is a SIngle Processor with 2 cores.

For instance, the i7-4970 is a Single CPU with 4 cores in Hyperthreading (you may consider like 8 cores).

Comment: It was as I thought, thanks.